# Is there a way for Gmail to filter incoming messages where sender's address is in your Contacts?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels, google-contacts

While Gmail does have some fuzzy intelligence with categorizing/flagging email when the sender address is in your contacts, is it possible to create a rule that explicitly performs some action of your choosing for any incoming mail where the sender's address is in Contacts? (Bonus: I want to also differentiate between contacts I manually enter vs the "auto-created contacts" that appear there.)

*Simple example:* I want to create a label called "From Contacts" and have a rule that applies said label to any incoming mail where the sender's email (or reply-to, if possible) is one of ***any*** of the addresses in my Gmail Contacts. Is this possible using Gmail's rules tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be possible, but it would require adding/specifying each contact manually to the filter which will assign the label to the received emails.

As for the differentiation between auto-added contacts and "created by you" contacts... this would be purely up to your tracking skills.

Comment: So what you're saying is that there is no function in GMail that determines whether an email address is in your Contacts, yes?

Comment: @DarfNader yes indeed.

Comment: Thanks. Bad news is still better than no news.